# Product quantity -1 and backorders

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, configuration, backorder

Backorders are disabled in system > configuration > catalog > inventory but a customer bought a product with quantity 0, so after he purchased it, product's quantity became -1. 
How is it possible?
I want that the customers can't buy a product with quantity 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check below setting

In particular product setting -> Inventory -> Backorders set to "No Backorders".

System-> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options -> Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock set to "0".

Refer below Inventory settings.

[image]

May be helpful to you.